# what are the prerequisite for installing oracle 11gr2

Tags: oracle, installation

I have windows 2008 R2 sever and I want install oracle 11gr2 on this server. So any one tell me what are the prerequisite tools for install oracle 11gr2 like as a jdk and ect...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this out:
[https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/install.112/e47798/reqs.htm#NTDBI002][1]
[http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/install.111/b32006/reqs.htm][2]
Probably you will get answers for such questions quickly if you google them.

Comment: Thanx you, But I can't get full understand with this document, because I am not familiar with this, Could you please list down one by one here with link that plance to download this tools..

Comment: What tools you want? Do you have oracle binaries? Then go ahead install it after looking at the requisites.

Comment: Tools mean like as a jdk or any other compilers.

Comment: Here you go -- http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/apps-tech/jdbc-112010-090769.html

Comment: Here you go -- http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk7-downloads-1880260.html